# Converting date from timestamp to epoch in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to do a one-time conversion of a bunch of dates (ex. 2017-04-22 02:25:26.830) into the unix epoch format via PostgreSQL query

I'm trying variations on:

```
UPDATE items
SET processed_date = date_part('epoch', timestamp processed_date)
WHERE source = 'mysourcevalue'
```

The field is text and should return text

Comment: Can you give us the data type of processed_date? I'm assuming it's text? 
And I'm also assuming that the date going back in is simply text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell from your question if the "dates" are strings or timestamps.  But these do what you want:

```
select v.*,
       extract(epoch from datestr::timestamp),
       date_part('epoch', datestr::timestamp)
from (values ('2017-04-22 02:25:26.830')) v(datestr)
```

You should be able to do:

```
UPDATE items
    SET processed_date = date_part('epoch', processed_date::timestamp)::text
WHERE source = 'mysourcevalue';
```

I'm pretty sure that Postgres will convert the number back to a string automatically, but being explicit is nice.

Comment: The 'dates' are strings.  I'm uncertain as to how to make this work --- where do i put in table name /column name?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE items
SET processed_date = timestamp 'epoch' + processed_date/1000 * interval '1 second'
WHERE source = 'mysourcevalue'
```